# Special prices are not displaying in magento

Tags: price

special prices are not displaying here. but we mentioned values for both prices and special prices. no "from-date" and to-date" set for special price. we can found special prices values  in admin panel. but it's displaying in frontend.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes?

Comment: Take care that the special prices have to be lower then the original ones.

Comment: yes @Marius, I did.... thanks  a lot for replying for my post again....

Comment: @sebastianwagner please post your comment as answer. thanks a lot

Comment: @sebastianwagner hi, i imported all products using csv file. 

In the "price" and "special price" columns , i swap the values of "price" and "special price" missly .

i wasted lot of time for find out this....

really i am an idiot....  i imported about 200 products which is having both prices and special prices. now again i have to import all products....

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Marius hi, i imported all products using csv file. 

In the "price" and "special price" columns , i swap the values of "price" and "special price" missly .

i wasted lot of time for find out this....

really i am an idiot....  i imported about 200 products which is having both prices and special prices. now again i have to import all products....

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care that the special prices have to be lower then the original ones.